# Why does my page display multiple questions when I only want one?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to display one question at a time. My question page displays every question from my database when I only want one question then hit the "next button" to move on to the next question. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

index.php

```
<?php require_once 'config.php';?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/watch.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#demo1').stopwatch().stopwatch('start');
    var steps = $('form').find(".questions");
    var count = steps.size();
    steps.each(function(i){
        hider=i+2;
        if (i == 0) {   
            $("#question_" + hider).hide();
            createNextButton(i);
        }
        else if(count==i+1){
            var step=i + 1;
            //$("#next"+step).attr('type','submit');
            $("#next"+step).on('click',function(){

               submit();

            });
        }
        else{
            $("#question_" + hider).hide();
            createNextButton(i);
        }

    });
    function submit(){
         $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajax.php",
                        data: $('form').serialize(),
                        success: function(msg) {
                          $("#quiz_form,#demo1").addClass("hide");
                          $('#result').show();
                          $('#result').append(msg);
                        }
         });

    }
    function createNextButton(i){
        var step = i + 1;
        var step1 = i + 2;
        $('#next'+step).on('click',function(){
            $("#question_" + step).hide();
            $("#question_" + step1).show();
        });
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
          submit();
    }, 50000);
});

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(msg) {
              $("#quiz_form,#demo1").addClass("hide");
              $('#result').show();
              $('#result').append(msg);
            }
         });
</script>



<title>Demo Gird</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'/>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Quiz using PHP, jQuery, Ajax and MySQL</h1>
<body>

<?php $response=mysql_query("select * from questions");?>
<form method='post' id='quiz_form'>
<?php while($result=mysql_fetch_array($response)){ ?>
<div id="question_<?php echo $result['id'];?>" class='questions'>
<h2 id="question_<?php echo $result['id'];?>"><?php echo $result['id'].".".$result['question_name'];?></h2>
<div class='align'>
<input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'>
<label id='ans1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['answer1'];?></label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" value="2" id='radio2_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'>
<label id='ans2_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['answer2'];?></label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" value="3" id='radio3_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'>
<label id='ans3_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['answer3'];?></label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" value="4" id='radio4_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'>
<label id='ans4_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['answer4'];?></label>
<input type="radio" checked='checked' value="5" style='display:none' id='radio4_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" id='next<?php echo $result['id'];?>' value='Next!' name='question' class='butt'/>
</div>
<?php }?>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$response=mysql_query("select id,question_name,answer from questions");
     $i=1;
     $right_answer=0;
     $wrong_answer=0;
     $unanswered=0;
     while($result=mysql_fetch_array($response)){ 
           if($result['answer']==$_POST["$i"]){
               $right_answer++;
           }else if($_POST["$i"]==5){
               $unanswered++;
           }
           else{
               $wrong_answer++;
           }
           $i++;
     }
     echo "<div id='answer'>";
     echo " Right Answer  : <span class='highlight'>". $right_answer."</span><br>";

     echo " Wrong Answer  : <span class='highlight'>". $wrong_answer."</span><br>";

     echo " Unanswered Question  : <span class='highlight'>". $unanswered."</span><br>";
     echo "</div>";
?>
```

thank you

Comment: because you are looping through all the questions

Comment: @ponciste I know that I have the while loop running to get each questions from database but how do I get the program to display question 1 and answer choices then have a next button which will take me to the next question?

Answer (score 0):

You get all questions because in `index.php` file you have a query which fetches all questions and then a `while` loop which loops through all questions and displayed them:

```
<?php $response=mysql_query("select * from questions");?>
<form method='post' id='quiz_form'>
<?php while($result=mysql_fetch_array($response)){ ?>
```

Comment: I know I'm calling a loop but I'm not sure if it has to do with jquery 1.9.1.min.js file I downloaded. If anything how would I be able to display one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Best and easiest to assign each item to a class and store these in an array as you go through your loop. Each item is then easily displayed by moving through the array

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are fetching all rows from table.

`<?php $response=mysql_query("select * from questions");?>`

use

`<?php $response=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1");?>`

It will fetch 1 row randomly from Database.